# Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore, solr4, sitecore8.1

I am configuring solar and lucen both together for different index (master and web ) in sitecore . I am using 4.1 solar and sitecore 8.1.

I've enable both Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration and Sitecore.ContentSearch.lucen.DefaultIndexConfiguration config and respective index config. while rebulding the index I am getting below error

```
Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
```

What are the possible causes for above error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.dll` is not in your `bin` directory.

Download `Solr support package` for your Sitecore version from `dev.sitecore.net` and copy dlls from it.